Can we diff multiple stacks at once using cdktf?
I've tried to plan multiple stacks using CDK for Terraform by providing the following command cdktf diff stack1 stack2 stack3, but it is showing the diff for the first stack only. Is there anyway we can get the diff for multiple or all stacks using cdktf diff command?

if you run cdktf diff -h it will show you how to use it:
cdktf diff [stack]
 
Perform a diff (terraform plan) for the given stack
 
Positionals:
  stack  Diff stack which matches the given id only. Required when more than one stack is present in the app                                                                    [string]

diff can compare 2 items at a time, your local and the given one.
